# Extract in R Raster Package incredibly slow

Tags: raster, r, sf

I am using the extract function from the raster package in R.

The extract function is taking incredibly long to assign the values to the polygon. In ArcMap, this process is much faster (but of course more time consuming to set up).

CVsteepslope is the raster (100m resolution) and grids (3,000,000 objects) is my polygon.

Here is the code:

```
CVsteepslope <- CVsteepslope %>% 
  projectRaster(CVsteepslope, crs="EPSG:3035")
# here I am reducing the raster to the polygon extent in an attempt to speed things up
CVsteepslope <- crop(CVsteepslope, extent(gridsdiss), snap="out")
  CVsteepslope <- rasterize(gridsdiss, CVsteepslope)
    CVsteepslope <- mask(x=CVsteepslope, mask=CVp) 
grids$steepslope <- as.numeric(extract(CVsteepslope, grids, method='bilinear', small=TRUE, fun=mean))
```

Side note: I am using a virtual environment with 128 gb memory, R is only using a third of this.

Comment: You could try the "exactextractr" package from CRAN: "exactextractr: Fast Extraction from Raster Datasets using Polygons". We can't really test anything without your data (or something like it) to see if its faster than `raster::extract`

Comment: Did you bother to read the answer to your previous post? You were aimed to exactextractr, by this same person, and responded that that is what you were looking for. I also posted methods and benchmarks that clearly show that you would not want to use `raster::extract`. https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/393822/extract-all-bands-as-weighted-mean-values-of-a-multiband-raster-to-polygons-r/393830#393830

Comment: Hey @JeffreyEvans I did read the answer to my previous post, apologies for the duplicate. I should have deleted this one, it doesn't specify that I am interested in extracting all of the values from a multiband to a polygon. On the post you linked, I marked yours as the answer.

Comment: Also, thank you for taking the time to answer my questions :) @JeffreyEvans

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are tons of question on how to speed up extraction in r, [for example this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/130522/increasing-speed-of-crop-mask-extract-raster-by-many-polygons-in-r).
Furthermore you did not give any example date to test you code or to generate better code.
However, as @Spacedman said in the comment the best option so far is `exact_extract()` from `exactextractr`  package ([more detail here](https://github.com/isciences/exactextractr)). Some example below

```
library(exactextractr)  
library(raster)
library(maptools)
library(sf)
library(terra)
## Example SpatialPolygonsDataFrame
data(wrld_simpl) #polygon of world countries
wrld_simpl_sf <- st_as_sf(wrld_simpl)

## Example RasterLayer
r <- raster(nrow=2e3, ncol=2e3, crs=proj4string(wrld_simpl), xmn=-180, xmx=180, 
ymn=-90, ymx=90)
r[] <- 1:length(r)

#plot, so you can see it
plot(r)    
plot(wrld_simpl, add=TRUE) 


# extract -----------------------------------------------------------------


rr <- rast(r)
v <- vect(wrld_simpl)

system.time(e1 <- raster::extract(r,wrld_simpl,small=T,method="bilinear",fun=mean))#76 
sec
system.time(e2 <- terra::extract(rr,v,method="bilinear",fun=mean))#5 sec
system.time(e3 <- exact_extract(r,wrld_simpl_sf,fun="mean"))#0.61sec
```

For now, the function takes only polygons object (not points, not lines), but is super fast and accurate (don't need option small=TRUE). It also returns the fraction of cell coverage by polygons

Comment: To use `terra::extract` you need to do something like `rr <- rast(r); w <- vect(wrld_simpl); e2 <- extract(rr, w, fun=mean)`. This is because `extract` is a *generic* function. What gets executed depends on the argument(s) supplied. If you do `terra::extract(RasterLayer)` the `raster::extract` method will be used (thankfully).

Comment: Sorry, I've forgotten 2 lines of code. I edited my answer, to take into account the class of the input in `terra::extract`

Answer (score 2):

`extract` function from `raster` package is quite slow when you are extracting data from a big raster or you have many polygons. A good alternative is using the `extract` function from package `terra`. This package is an updated version of `raster`. It works better with native formats `SpatVector` and `SpatRaster`. Therefore, the way to proceed is converting your files to these formats and then extract.

```
library(terra)

# convert to native format
poly<-vect(grids)
rs<-rast(CVsteepslope)

# extract
example<-terra::extract(rs,poly)
```

More info about `terra` package: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/terra/terra.pdf