# Extract all band values of a multiband raster to Polygons as separate columns

Tags: raster, r, multi-band

I am trying to extract the values of a multiband raster to a polygon in R.

```
ACVheatingdegreedayS <- stack("location/multibandraster.tif")
ACVheatingdegreedayS <- ACVheatingdegreedayS %>% 
  projectRaster(ACVheatingdegreedayS, crs="EPSG:3035")

( zCVhdd1 <- CVheatingdegreedayS[[1]] )
```

I want to avoid that last line of code where I break the multiband into a single band. There are 70 bands, so creating separate rasters would be very time consuming.

Anyone know of a way to extract all bands of a multiband raster to a polygon?

Comment: II would recommenced the `exactextractr::exact_extract` function. It benchmarks, by far, the fastest of all the options. There is also `raster::extract`, `terra::extract` and a pure tidy approach using `tabularaster::cellnumbers` but, it is not as straight forward to use as the others.

Comment: Where's the polygon here? Do we care about the `projectRaster`? Is `CVheatingdegreedayS` a typo for `ACVheatingdegreedayS`? Why can't you loop over 1 to 70? Have you not done a basic R course where you find out about loops?

Comment: thanks! the extact_extractr package was what I was looking for, not so much advice on how to make a loop.

Comment: Question still isn't clear. Where's the weights, and where's the values you are finding the weighted mean of?

Comment: I would like the average of all pixels values covering each polygon weighted by how much they cover the pixel. I am interested in creating a variable in the polygons for each raster band @Spacedman

Comment: Then your question should say something like "I have polygons P and a multiband raster R and I want the mean of cells of each band R[[i]] inside each polygon P[[j]] including fractions of cells where the polygons cross cells". Is that better?

Comment: yes exactly! apologies for the unclear language. @Spacedman

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some general methods for multi-band raster extraction and summary along with benchmarks. The main difference in multi-band verses single-band is how the data is summarized. If you want a mean weighted by the intersection of cell sizes the easiest route is `exactextractr::exact_extract`. This function actually has a weighted.mean option, as the output, that is calculated in the C++ routine (detailed in functions help). The "raw" results from this function includes the fractional intersection for each intersecting cell so, you could calculate something yourself.

I would note that the different methods of summary are not really adding to the benchmark results, times are reflective of how long it takes to extract the data from the raster stack.

Add libraries and create some data

```
library(sf)
library(raster)
library(terra)
library(exactextractr)
library(tabularaster)
library(dplyr)

nc <- st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package="sf"))
  nc <- st_cast(nc, "POLYGON")

i=500; j=500
r <- do.call(raster::stack, replicate(20, 
             raster::raster(matrix(runif(i*j), i, j)))) 
    extent(r) <- extent(nc)
      proj4string(r) <- st_crs(nc)$proj4string

plot(r[[1]])
  plot(st_geometry(nc), add=TRUE)
```

We can now run through and benchmark each method from `raster`, `exactextract`, `terra` and `tabularaster`. For a gut check, the results of each method are held in the eresult list object.

```
eresults <- list()

# raster::extract 
system.time({
  v.raster <- raster::extract(r, nc)
  eresults[["raster"]] <-   
    do.call("rbind", lapply(v.raster, function(x) apply(x, MARGIN=2, mean))) 
})

# terra::extract 
system.time({
  v.terra <- terra::extract( rast(r), vect(nc))
  eresults[["terra"]] <-    
  do.call("rbind", lapply(unique(v.terra[,"ID"]), function(i) 
        apply(v.terra[v.terra$ID==i,], MARGIN=2, mean))) 
})

# exactextractr 
system.time({
  v.exact <- exactextractr::exact_extract(r, nc) 
  eresults[["exactextract"]] <-    
    do.call("rbind", lapply(v.exact, function(x) apply(x, MARGIN=2, mean)))[,-21] 
})

# tabularaster using raster 
system.time({
  index <- cellnumbers(r[[1]], nc)
    index %>% 
      group_by(object_) %>% 
        count()     
  result <- index %>% 
     mutate(pixelvalue = raster::extract(r, cell_)) %>% 
       as.data.frame() 
    eresults[["tabularaster"]] <-    
       aggregate(result[,3:ncol(result)], by=list(result$object_), mean)       
})
```

Comment: The Q asks about "Extracting all bands to a polygon" which seems unclear. Do they want to polygonize each band of a raster? Do they want to crop to a polygon?

Comment: @Spacedman I am going on "extract the values of a multiband raster to a polygon" but, you are correct, it is very unclear exactly what the OP is after here.

Comment: @JeffreyEvans and Spacedman Thank you for all the help. I'm fairly new to R so please excuse my poor communication of what I'm trying to accomplish. Spacedman got it here: "I have polygons P and a multiband raster R and I want the mean of cells of each band R[[i]] inside each polygon P[[j]] including fractions of cells where the polygons cross cells". I'll update you on how this goes.

Comment: what is the aim of [,-21] in exactextractr? Is it necessary? Thanks!

Comment: @FraNut The index is just dropping the column containing the fractional cell intersections. The index would be unique to each problem (number of bands in your data) and not necessary if you want to keep this data. If you wanted to automate it you could do something like `[,-(nlayers(x)+1)]` which would denote the last column. I also believe that in newer versions of `exactextractr` there is an argument to omit this column at the function call level.